# Parse XML in jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, xml, parsing, xml-parsing

I posted earlier today ([Old Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12350245/jquery-help-parse-xml-into-array)) asking for help to parse XML. I did not realise at the time that the solution did not fully solve my problem.

My issue is that although I can parse the XML by finding individual elements, I need to take a note of what level each item is under. The number of items and categories varies for each XML doc, but are all structured the same way.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
<game>
    <title>Dementia</title>
        <cat>
            <catTitle>Mild</catTitle>
            <item>mild-1</item>
            <item>mild-2</item>
            <item>mild-3</item>
        </cat>
        <cat>
            <catTitle>Moderate</catTitle>
            <item>Moderate-1</item>
            <item>Moderate-2</item>
            <item>Moderate-3</item>
        </cat>
        <cat>
            <catTitle>Severe</catTitle>
            <item>Severe-1</item>
            <item>Severe-2</item>
        </cat>
</game>
```

For example, when 'find("item")' is used, I need it to also take a note of which  it was under (0,1,2,3,4 etc). The same is needed for the catTitle.

I would then want to assign this  number as an attribute. This will allow me to easily compare if the item matches to its category, based on the .

Currently I have the following:

```
    //XML Array
///////////////////////////////////////
function loadXML(){
  $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: XML_PATH,
        dataType: "xml",
        success: parseXMLtoArray
        }); 
}

function parseXMLtoArray(xml){

$(xml).find("cat").each(function(idx, v) {
    categoryArrays[idx] = [];

    $(v).find("item").each(function( i , vi) {
        categoryArrays[idx].push( $(vi).text() );
    });             
});
console.log(categoryArrays);
}
///////////////////////////////////////
```

To give a better understanding of what the purpose for this I have attached a screenshot:

The user drags the 'item' to its correct category at the bottom, then based on if it is correct or not, it is droppable. 
[image: Interactive jQuery Test]

**Any help would be GREATLY appreciated!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. I parsed the XML into arrays and created an object for each item also, adding an attribute (.attr) of its category, so that it could be called later.

```
//XML Array
///////////////////////////////////////
function loadXML(){
  $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: XML_PATH,
        dataType: "xml",
        success: parseXMLtoArray
        }); 
}


function parseXMLtoArray(xml){

$(xml).find("cat").each(function(idx, v) {
    categoryArrays[idx] = [];

    $(v).find("catTitle").each(function(){

        //$(xml).find('title:contains("Dimentia")').each(function(){
        numberofCategories = numberofCategories+1;
        tmpCategory = $(this).text();
        categoryNames.push(tmpCategory);

        var $item = $('<div>' + tmpCategory + '</div>').fadeIn('slow').appendTo('#catPile').attr('categoryName', tmpCategory).attr('categoryNum', idx).droppable({
            containment: '#content',
            stack: '#catPile div',
            cursor: 'move',
            drop: handleDropEvent
        });

    });



    //ITEM PARSING
        $(v).find("item").each(function( i , vi) {
            categoryArrays[idx].push( $(vi).text() );

            numberofItems = numberofItems+1;
            tmpItem = $(this).text();

            //Add Item to Array
            itemNames.push(tmpItem);

                   //UI CREATION and Atrribute setting
                    var $item = $('<div>' + tmpItem + '</div>').fadeIn('slow').appendTo('#itemPile').attr('itemName', tmpItem).attr('categoryNum', categoryArrayNum).draggable({
                        containment: '#content',
                        stack: '#itemPile div',
                        cursor: 'move',
                        revert: true
                    });

                    console.log("Item Created: " + tmpItem + " // Item's Category:" + categoryArrayNum) ;

        });


    console.log('-- Category Array Num: ' + categoryArrayNum + ' contains: ' + categoryArrays[categoryArrayNum]);
    categoryArrayNum++;
});

console.log("// ITEMS ASSIGNED TO CATEGORIES");
}
```

Hope this helps someone!